# Vim: typing closing double quote adds a newline and indents, instead of wrapping

Tags: vim

When I enter code that exceeds the textwidth, it wraps it as it should...

```
13 something
14     "long long (...) long
   long long string
15
```

...but then when I hit closing double quote (") it does this:

```
13 something
14     "long long (...) long
15     long long string"
```

How to fix this? I don't want a newline and indent, I want it to work like this:

```
13 something
14    "long long (...) long
   long long string"
15
```

here are my indent/wrapping setting in _vimrc:

```
set expandtab "spaces for tabs
set smarttab
" 1 tab == 4 spaces
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4 
set softtabstop=4

set autoindent
set smartindent
set cindent

set backspace=2 "backspace work normal
set whichwrap+=<,>,h,l "backspace, cursor keys wrap to next/prev lines
```

Comment: What gives `:set tw`?

Comment: I can't imagine Vim doing this by default. What plugins are you using, what's the filetype and what are your format options? `:set ft? fo?`.

Comment: `textwidth=79 filetype=python formatoptions=tcq`, no plugins installed, gvim on windows (to be clear)

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Can you post your actual code and your actual vimrc, please? This code is not valid Python.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this either, and if you are writing Python code, why would you want it to not indent anyway?